# xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() returns only one header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

We have Node.js as a server which helps in getting us remote rest service, from client html I am trying to get response headers from the jQuery Ajax call using below code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: newUrl,
  crossDomain: true,
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    var responseText = JSON.stringify(data);
    alert(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
  },
  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

But the problem is, I only get one one response header: `Content-Type: application/json` remaining things are ignored. From my research I found that I need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to make that available. So in Node I tried like this:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
});
```

But still I get only the one header `Content-Type`. Can you help in identifying this issue? By the way, it's a cross domain calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I am able to resolve this issue, from the `Node.js` side. 
I added both

> **Access-Control-Expose-Headers** and **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**

to the response header in node.js. This solved my issue. Earlier I was having only `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Comment: @blunderboy, SO requires 2 days time to accept OP's own answer :)

Answer (score 2):

What header do you want? Add it to Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (I'm not sure whether CORS header show up or not, though you probably won't need them.)

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Header1, Header2, Header3'
```